# NSTableView effeciency in loading over many objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can someone advise me of any techniques in displaying a table with over 5k objects?

My NSTableView can only display about 10 objects at a time. The table's dataSource is an array of over 5k objects. Is there any idea on how i can only allocate the objects in that array so that the maximum objects in the array at any given time will be the amount displayed on the screen?

Any ideas to point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: have you noticed a performance problem? if so, you should use Instruments to profile where your slow down is. then you will know what to speed up.

Comment: ... This depends entirely on how you get the objects, and without knowing that, no one can help you. And 5k objects in an array should not be a problem.

Comment: So table views can handle super large numbers of rows. But that said you really need to give a lot more info on what the data source objects are and how you are populating data. Are you using bindings? Cell based or view based? Data source delegate? If so post code and more detail.

Comment: I have not noticed a performance problem, but 5k is average minimum. The objects items count in the array can grow to over 600k average maximum.  The items are stored in separate plist files. Each single item is a NSDictionary within a plist file. I allocate the obj items by running a loop on the plist, and instantiating each dictionary into an obj item. So im basically (right now) allocating all plist objects in the file.. all up-to 600k objects.. but table can only show few at a time.. i think that inefficient.. right? So i was wondering if there was some technique to help with that.

Comment: Also each instantiated dictionary object is pretty huge. Containing instantiated objects of their own and other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is premature optimization, 5k objects is not going to affect the performance, just allocate the array with no capacity.

**Edit:** If you are having side effects you should consider applying lazy initialization or the flyweight pattern.

Comment: His question is not entirely without reason... Don't forget the rest of the quote:"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." But your answer is correct, so +1.

Comment: I have updated the question above. Will this still not be a problem? If not, i will instantiate all the objects...

Comment: @CaptJak after becoming far mor experience in iOS than i was 2 years ago, i realized this answer wasnt the best and have removed it as being correct. Instantiating 5k objects that kill an iPhone's memory will not work.

Comment: @Jay after becoming far mor experienced in iOS than I was 2 years ago, I still think that's premature optimization if you are reusing and following the table view practices, and maybe have data source and delegate as a external injected class

Comment: @RafaelGonçalves I do not understand what you mean. I certainly am following table view practices. I there is nothing wrong with the tableView, it displays and reuses the cells just fine. The part i was wondering about was the dataSource. Do you still think its a good idea to instantiate 5k objects?

Comment: Being serious now, I don't know which context you have to instantiate 5k obj but if this is bothering you or having any side effects then it's not premature opmitization and you should think about using patterns like lazy initialization or the flyweight pattern. @Jay

Comment: Thanks. Now if you add these 2 suggestions to your answer now, i will re-select your answer as being correct :)
I ended up doing lazy initialization. Because Instancing so many `Heavy` objects all at once was having negative side effects in performance.

Comment: Nah. you were not rude. Thanks for the update. I selected it as the answer.